# Check belonging before deletion

Tags: django

This is working for me, I am just wondering if it is the "safe" or recommended way of doing things.

```
def yours(obj, request):
    if obj.user == request.user:
        return True
    else:
        return False

@login_required
def classroom_delete(request, pk, template_name='reports/classroom_confirm_delete.html'):

    classroom = get_object_or_404(Classroom, pk=pk)

    # Is this enough?
    if not yours(classroom, request):
        HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

I am going to implement it in all my delete functions which delete objects that have foreign keys to users.

Comment: This looks like a good approach. Also, in the template I would just not show the delete option if `obj.user != request.user`

Comment: I took care of that with `classrooms = Classroom.objects.filter(user=request.user)` But that's a great idea for later!

Comment: Ok.. You can just do `return obj.user == request.user`

Comment: Oh, that's true. Make it a 2-liner.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up looking for all my `get_object_or_404` functions and checked without the function.

```
classroom = get_object_or_404(Classroom, pk=pk)
if classroom.user != request.user:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Because I found I needed to do stuff like this anyway:

```
student = get_object_or_404(Student, pk=pk)
if student.classroom.user != request.user:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```